# Limit the extent of scipy.signal.correlate

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, signal-processing

I'm using scipy.signal.correlate to align two arrays of the same size (which contain images of the same object taken at different times). I first do a rough alignment by finding the brightest spot in each image (not a robust method, but it works for this image set) so I know the images are almost aligned.

So, I don't want to compute the full correlation between the arrays (as doing so is very computationally intensive, and I don't need most of the information obtained), just the correlation within, say, +/- 10% of on-center alignment.
I'm currently using:

```
corr = signal.correlate(im1_bw, im2_bw, mode="same")
```

the mode=same flag gets me a little closer, but as these are very high resolution images,
not really close enough. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a friend:
If you crop one image less aggressively and use 'valid', you'll get what you want.  If it's (w1 x h1) and (w2 x h2) the resulting correlation signal should have size (w1-w2 +1 x h1-h2+1), corresponding to all the possible shifts of the smaller within the bigger.﻿
(i.e., pass unequally-sized images and use 'valid')﻿

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is Patrick Foley.

So this might be a dumb hack (it definitely is a dumb hack) but what about just downsampling your images and then computing that correlation?

Comment: Hey Patrick!
For this particular application, I'm actually up-sampling the images to try and do sub-pixel alignment. So that wouldn't be the way to go.

Comment: Cool.  Superresolution is the greatest.